# How secure are third party Ubuntu (APT) repository mirrors

Tags: ubuntu, security, debian, apt

We use local Ubuntu repository mirrors, because our external traffic is not free.  Whenever I `apt-get install "program"` it gets from that repository.

The question is... can the maintainers of the repository substitute any package on the repository with their own package?

Can I be hacked easily on any `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get install` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

We get very basic packages from the local Ubuntu mirrors, such as "telnet" or any other.

Comment: Who are 'they' that you are concerned about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are plenty of mechanisms to secure a repo, including package signing and so on, they're only as secure as the maintainer makes them.  A poorly managed third-party repo that gets hacked or is run by a malicious individual could indeed install hostile software.

Answer (score 10):

No.

All packages and indexes (Packages.gz,Sources.gz,...) should be signed using a GPG key. Also apt uses md5sum to verify that it has downloaded a correct copy of the Packages index file.

If someone replaces or modifies a package, the package will no longer match GPG sign.

Comment: sorry for further stupid question, can they substitute GPG keys as well? Those Packages.gz and Sources.gz are coming from where then?

Comment: @baketn Without the secret key, you can just remove the signature. Signature files need a secret key. You also need to add the public key in local trust database.

Answer (score 1):

Both Debian and Ubuntu APT repositories have multiple levels of checks made before a package is available for you to download. Initial uploads of packages by developers are GPG signed along with including multiple checksums on the individual files comprising the package upload that then have both the checksums and the GPG signature verified before being accepted. Then the repository itself has it's own GPG key that is used to sign the release files listing the available packages in the repository. The release files for the repository also include checksum data that the various APT-based install utilities then verify as well as the GPG signature on the release files itself.

So from upload by the developer maintaining the package to download and installation on your local machine there is a method to verify that nothing has been tampered with or altered.